# Pytest do endless collecting of tests and doesb`t start

Tags: python, django, pytest

When I am running pytest command it starts to collect all tests, but this process is endless without any errors or mistakes. I don't understand what is the reason. If you have any ideas, please could you share them? Also if it helps I run it on MacOS, on my Ubuntu computer it works perfect.

This is what happened:

```
Test session starts (platform: linux, Python 3.7.3, pytest 5.0.1, pytest-sugar 0.9.2)
Django settings: settings (from ini file)
rootdir: /home/roziukp/space11/backend, inifile: setup.cfg
plugins: xdist-1.29.0, forked-1.0.2, pythonpath-0.7.3, env-0.6.2, django-3.5.1, sugar-0.9.2, celery-4.3.0, cov-2.7.1, mock-1.10.4
collecting ...
```

Comment: Not enough info, but most probably you have some large dir in your repo (like `.tox` or virtual env dir) that is not excluded from test collection. First, run `pytest tests/` (substitute `tests/` with the name of your test dir) to check whether the tests are collected fast when narrowing the search source. Then list the contents of your project dir and add all the nonrelevant directories to `norecursedirs`. Check out [Changing directory recursion](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html?highlight=norecursedirs#changing-directory-recursion) for configuration example.

Answer (score 1):

Set the following configuration in your **pytest.ini** file.

```
testpaths = application/tests
norecursedirs = .git .tox .pytest_cache
python_files = test_*.py
```